# Braintree onReady not firing within Angular application

Tags: angularjs, braintree

I'm using the [Braintree Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+node/guides/hosted-fields/overview) within my Angular application. When the app loads, the `braintree.setup('TOKEN', 'customer', {})` works as intended. The `onReady` fires correctly.

**This is my controller:**

```
angular.module('braintree')
  .controller('BraintreeCtrl', [
    function() {

      var self = this;

      self.setup = function() {
        console.log('setup braintree');

        braintree.setup('myBTtoken', 'custom', {
          id: 'braintreeForm',
          onReady: function() {
            console.log('on ready');
          },
          hostedFields: {
            styles: {},
            number: {
              selector: '#card-number',
              placeholder: 'Card number'
            },
            cvv: {
              selector: '#card-cvv',
              placeholder: 'CVV'
            },
            expirationMonth: {
              selector: '#card-expiration-month',
              placeholder: 'MM'
            },
            expirationYear: {
              selector: '#card-expiration-year',
              placeholder: 'YY'
            },
            postalCode: {
              selector: '#card-postal',
              placeholder: 'Postal code'
            }
          }
        });
      }     
    }
  ]);
```

**View (in jade):**

```
  form(name='braintreeForm', id='braintreeForm', novalidate, ng-init='ctrl.setup()')
    .form-group
      label Card Number
      #card-number

    .form-group
      label CVV
      #card-cvv

    .form-group
      label Expires
      #card-expiration-month

    .form-group
      #card-expiration-year

    .form-group
      label Zip Code
      #card-postal

    button(type='submit') Submit
```

However, when I navigate away from this page, then COME BACK to this state where the `BraintreeCtrl` fires, the `onReady` never fires and I can't enter any data.

**How can I re-setup braintree when I come back to the state with my braintree form??**

Answer (score 2):

*I work at Braintree on the JavaScript SDK*

As of right now there is not an officially supported mechanism for this. It is an issue that we are aware of and we will provide a solution in a future release. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a timeline for this work.

In the meantime, I recommend contacting our support team (support@braintreepayments.com) and keeping an eye on related threads on our [Github](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/29). Again, while there is no officially supported solution, people have found some [interesting workarounds](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/29#issuecomment-103986438).

I'm sorry I don't have better news, but we appreciate you raising this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, `braintree.setup()` could only be called once without bugging out.

They have now implemented the `teardown()` function which will allow you to call `braintree.setup()` again.

In short, call the `teardown()` when you want to destroy the session - perhaps upon leaving the page.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/javascript/v2#teardown
https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/29